# How to write query in PromQL and assign it to a variable for alert conditions?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql, observability, signalfx

I have a below query from SignalFx and i need to convert it to PromQL:

```
A =   data('signal_apiserver_graphql.errors_count', filter=filter('kubernetes_cluster', 'dev-001', 'dev-003', 'dev-002', 'dev-000'), warmup='sum').sum(by=['kubernetes_cluster']).sum(over='10m').publish(label='A', enable=False)

B = data('signal_apiserver_graphql.errors_count', filter=filter('kubernetes_cluster', 'dev-001', 'dev-003', 'dev-002', 'dev-000'), warmup='average', extrapolation='zero').sum(by=['kubernetes_cluster', 'account']).count(by=['kubernetes_cluster']).sum(over='10m').publish(label='B', enable=False)
```

How do I write the corresponding PromQL and assign it to a variable or label A for later use for creating alerts and executing something like the below:
A < B then generate alerts.

Comment: You need to figure out what kind of alert you intend to create: [Prometheus alert rule](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/alerting_rules/) or [Grafana alert](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/alerting/). Additionally, names of metrics in Prometheus will be beneficial too. And finally description of what you have been doing with your current query: I feel like Prometheus' aproach to store error count will be based on counters, and it might require a bit of overhaul to work.

Comment: Check if something like `sum by (kubernetes_cluster) (increase(signal_apiserver_graphql_errors_total{kubernetes_cluster=~"dev-00[0-3]"}[10m]))` (but with correct names for metrics and labels) returns similar result to your previous query.